# Phoenix error: module Phoenix.Auth is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working through the phoenix book while working on my own project and I am getting this error:

```
== Compilation error in file web/router.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/router.ex:2: module Phoenix.Auth is not loaded and 
could not be found
expanding macro: ComicApp.Web.__using__/1
web/router.ex:2: ComicApp.Router (module)
(elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
web/router.ex:2: ComicApp.Router (module)
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in 
Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

Going to those pages the code looks like:

```
defmodule ComicApp.Router do
use ComicApp.Web, :router

pipeline :browser do
 plug :accepts, ["html"]
 plug :fetch_session
 plug :fetch_flash
 plug :protect_from_forgery
 plug :put_secure_browser_headers
 plug ComicApp.Auth, repo: ComicApp.Repo
end

pipeline :api do
 plug :accepts, ["json"]
end

scope "/", ComicApp do
 pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
 get "/", PageController, :index
 resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, 
:create]
  resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, 
:delete]

end

scope "/manage", ComicApp do
  pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]
  resources "/comics", ComicController
 end
end
```

this is my GitHub file: https://github.com/cggarcia171/ComicBookLibrary

Comment: I think you meant to use `ComicApp.Auth` and not `Phoenix.Auth`. Phoenix does not come with an `Auth` module.

Comment: your plug seems really weird, importing controller and such... take a look at this auth plug from guardian: https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/master/lib/guardian/plug/ensure_authenticated.ex